# loading site in iframe has error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, popup

I have a url that I want to load in an iframe that's inside a pop-up window. The parent window has a script that inserts a script to the pop-up window so that it the popup will refresh the parent window when the pop-up is closed.

```
function popUp(url) {
    newwindow = window.open('', 'mypopup', '');
    var tmp = newwindow.document;
    tmp.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>My Pop-Up</title></head>');
    tmp.write('<body><iframe src="' + url + '" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    tmp.write('<script type="text/javascript">window.onunload = function(){ window.opener.location.reload(); }</script></body></html>');
    tmp.close();
}
```

I chose to write the html via javascript because I can't edit the page being loaded (I need to really reload the parent when the pop-up is closed.) This works on chrome and firefox but IE has an error '**SCRIPT5: Access is denied.**' I'm not trying to access any part of the page that is being loaded in the iframe, I just want to load it.

When I open the page in a new IE tab, it loads fine. Also, if I load the url via showModalDialog(), the page loads. I wish I could just use showModalDialog() but when the save button is clicked on the pop-up page, another pop-up opens so I guess that's out of the question.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to check only when the pop up is **closed** then you can initiate external timer to check this:

```
var checkPopup = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (newwindow.closed) {
        window.clearInterval(checkPopup);
        document.location.reload();
    }
}, 100);
```

This way you don't rely on fancy scripting inside the pop up itself.

Comment: hey, hey! did that before i could check this thread again. thanks! :)